# Migrate Service Applications

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, service-application

I would like to know the approach to migrate following SharePoint 2010 service applications from one farm to another:

1. Managed Metadata
2. Project Service application
3. BCS
4. Secure Store Service Application

Answer (score 3):

For each service application, there is an underlying service application database where the real content lives. The process for each involves moving the database to the other farm SQL instance. To do that follow these steps:

1. Stop the Service Application
2. Detach the database from the current SQL Server
3. Move the Database files to the destination farm server
4. Attach to the databases to the correct SQL Server instance of that farm.
5. Point the Service Application to the migrated service application database.

   - For each service application you can use PowerShell to tie the service application database to each service application. Or, when you migrated it successfully, just recreate the service application, specifying the service application database name you migrated as the name of the "new" service application database for each of the service applications you migrated and listed.

For example: if you migrated the BCS Service Database correctly and it's database name was "BCS_Service_Application" then list that as the "new" database name for a new service application and it will make the connection.

[Rename or move service application databases for SharePoint Foundation 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff851877%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I am currently facing a problem with Managed Metadata migration. Issue is the domains are different. Due to this the ECMPermission table has old domain users. Because of this the Managed Metadata does not come up and term stores are not available. We can change the users in ECMPermission table to new users but directly changing database is not supported and hence stuck.

Comment: You can add the necessary database permissions after you attach the database, regardless of domains.